# Cannot create connection socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have a barebones `Express` app running socket.io listening locally on port `8001` and I have client server running socket.io-client listening on port `8000`.

When a request for connection is made from client to the socket server programmtically, it does not responsd to the incoming `"connection"` event. Now, if I go the browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8001` and now send a request from the client server it will start responding to the incoming "connection" events. I am not sure what the cause of this is? Any guidance is appreciated.

**Client-side**

```
  const socketioclient = require('socket.io-client');
  var ioClient: any;

 app.post("/makeconnection", (req, res) => {
    ioClient = socketioclient.connect("http://localhost:8001");
    res.send();
  });
```

**Server-side**

```
const io = require('socket.io');
var ioServer: any = {};

ioServer.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
    console.log("connected " + socket.id);
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      // remove socket
      console.log('socket disconnected and socket id is: ' + socket.id);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you try with a minor change on client server like this ioClient = socketioclient.connect("http://localhost:8001"); ioClient.on('connect',function(){
    res.send(); }); So basically send the response when ioClient is successfully connected

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it does not end the request so doesn't reach the res.send

Comment: can you try to remove express from the clientServer (just comment any code for a listening server) and connect direct const socketioclient = require('socket.io-client'); ioClient = socketioclient.connect("http://localhost:8001"); and call the program (if name is clientserver.js) node clientserver.js (it should make a connection)

Comment: I cannot remove the express from this app as our projects comes bundled with express and the details are abstracted out, that is one limitation i do have

Comment: I wanted to check where is he problem is, because if it was going to be directly connected then there is some issue in express app. One last thought is to make also an app.get('/makeconnection') (just copy paste it) and put below and call it also directly from the browser http://localhost:8000 (because in a post you have to call with a client like insomnia)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, created a client.js file and attempted to make a connection from that. Still experience the same behaviour on the server, only makes socket connections after I open a page in the browser that tries to hit an endpoint which does not exist :\

Comment: Issue resolved. It was our abstraction that was causing this issue and it was a timing issue with io was undefined on the first run but not subsequent